# Find Exact Match From Page Using Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to find exact match from my whole html.Below is the detail explanation.
Suppose i have html like below:

```
<html>
<body>
.....
<table>
<tr>
<td>
This is my linenumber
</td>
<td>
number
</td>
</tr>
</table>
.....
</body>
</html>
```

Here i want to replace 'number' word.
i can do this using `.replace(/number/g,'newnumber')` but by using this it is also changing value in 'This is my linenumber' statement, it will also convert this statement to 'This is my linenewnumber'.

I don't want to do it. I only need to change where there is single 'number',not with any word.

Comment: What behaviour would you want for `<td>Another number here</td>` - would you want that instance of `number` replacing as well?

Answer (score 2):

You want to match [**word boundaries**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml) using `\b`:

```
.replace(/\bnumber\b/g, 'newnumber');
```

Comment: Beat me *and* put an explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Try `.replace(/\bnumber\b/g,'newnumber')`

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("table tr td").each(function(){

    if($(this).text().trim() =='number')
    {
    $(this).text('newtext');
    }

});
});
```

or this with javascript

```
.replace(/\bnumber\b/g, 'newnumber');
```